# How to set where 0,0 coordinates are?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

By default, 0,0 coordinates are in the top, left corner. However, for my scene, it would be very helpful if it was in my bottom, left corner.

Is that even possible? If so, how can I set that?

Comment: Read [docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/group.html) about display groups.  Probably, it would be helpful.

Comment: Nah, what I need is the following: Now, when you go "up the screen", the y coordinate will get lower, but I need it to go higher. I hope you understand me.

Comment: @FICHEKK why is it not what you need? you want to move the origin for drawing and he told you to read the documentation about changing the origin (group tranforms)

Comment: @FICHEKK - Yes, if origin is at the left bottom corner, then y will be negative on visible area.  You should manually invert sign of y in all your expressions.

Comment: You may create a group and set `group.yScale = -1` so from now on, every object inserted into the group will go higher with higher Y values. Unfortunately everything will be mirrored.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mathematical approach which I think is a lot easier.
Simply define a function which converts your local Y coordinate to what Corona uses:

```
function localY ( y )
    return 600-y --Assuming your screen size is 600 pixels
end
```

Then simply use 
x, localY(y) instead of x,y

You can do the same for x if decided to change it.